# Power bi calculated column with filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate difference between two rows values based on index, index been calculated using RANKX and for each Symbol it may vary based on data available.

How to apply filters while adding new calculated column ? I have below code for new column ending with error ("A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected ")

Change = Sheet1[SCLOSE] - if(Sheet1[ranknew]=1, Sheet1[SCLOSE], LOOKUPVALUE(Sheet1[SCLOSE], Sheet1[ranknew],Sheet1[ranknew]-1))

[data for problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcDc.png)

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/community/47018/how-calculate-difference-between-consecutive-rows-columns

Comment: this helps me to solve